# gremlin query for the last element of multi property value of vertex

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, datastax-enterprise-graph

I want to modele data using vertex with multi-properties which has meta-properties, for exemple:

the multi-property "date" : `[12/12/2012, 13/12/2012, 19/12/2012, 24/12/2012]`
and meta property for each value of date, for example, `date: 12/12/2012 ("alimented" : "no")`.

How can I query the vertex to get the value of the last `date` inserted for given vertex. In the example, `date: 24/12/2012` with the corresponding meta-property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [order()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#order-step) step:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> v = g.addV().next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> v.property(list,'date',1, "alimented", "no")
==>vp[date->1]
gremlin> v.property(list,'date',2, "alimented", "yes")
==>vp[date->2]
gremlin> v.property(list,'date',3, "alimented", "no")
==>vp[date->3]
gremlin> g.V(v).properties('date').order().by(value,decr).limit(1).valueMap(true)
==>[key:date, value:3, alimented:no, id:3]
```

Obviously your "date" field needs to be something that can be sorted on via `Comparable`.